# What is better single or multiple routes for REST service?

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, iis

I have multi-tenant SaaS application and on startup I setup routes like this:

```
https://my.com/customer1/mobile 
https://my.com/customer1/integration
https://my.com/customer2/mobile 
https://my.com/customer2/integration
https://my.com/customer3/mobile 
https://my.com/customer3/integration
https://my.com/customer4/mobile 
https://my.com/customer4/integration
```

When I add new customer I have to recycle pool so routes rebuild. I'm not sure if that's the best approach for what I'm doing...

I can create just 2 routes

```
https://my.com/mobile 
https://my.com/integration
```

And then pass AccountId in HTTP header along with my auth information. Would it be cleaner? What do you think about performance, having less routes should be benefitial, correct?

Comment: What do you mean by *When I add new customer I have to recycle pool so routes rebuild*?

Comment: When I create new account new route/wcf endpoint need to be created on service. By customer I mean our company customer

Comment: I don't understand why you want to create a WCF route/endpoint everytime. You can set the Uritemplate such that you can avoid creating new routes everytime a new customer is added. Can you post the method signatures for mobile, integration methods.